# How to look variable at a pointer location in GDB?

Tags: iphone, exception, gdb

[ipad application] error message at console

***** -[CFSet release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xbdd9930 **

Above is the exception in GDB console, in my iPad Application, I want to see what variable or object is getting released how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're over-releasing either an NSSet or NSArray.  What you can do to monitor the addresses is use the Debugger window under Run --> Debugger.